# How to have one item div move while other does not while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website:
[image]

And I want the user to be able to scroll anywhere on the page, like they normally would, but I want the text to stay on the right in the same place while the images continue to move down. An similar idea is found on Apple's website on https://www.apple.com/apple-news/ where the magazines on the right of the screen move down faster than the magazines on the left side. How can I achieve this using pure css and js. It is key to note that this is not the only section of the website. There are going to be sections above and below this.

This is my html:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 40px;">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 80px; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Raleway';" id="lookAtThesePhotos">Look at these photos</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%;">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/hackers.jpg">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you provide your css code.  But basically, just adding `display: fixed` will do the work.

Comment: @JuliusGuevarra all the css code is inline; the problem with `position: fixed` is that it doesn't account for the other sections above and below this section. in other words, the words will will appear in all sections

Comment: Just asking, is it parallax effect that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *css positioning* and give value `sticky` to the text element

```
#lookAtThesePhotos {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```
<h1>Hola</h1>

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 40px;">
  <div>
    <span style="font-size: 80px; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Raleway';" id="lookAtThesePhotos">Look at these photos</span>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 50%;">
    <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/hackers.jpg">
    <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
    <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
    <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

The *look at these photos text* will scroll initially until it is displayed at top of the window. Then it remains fixed there and the images scroll through

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/uchihamalolan/pen/oOYJba

When the span element is at 0px, it'll behave as `fixed` element. Rest of the time it'll behave as *relatively positioned*.
Please note, `sticky` is a relatively new value for `position` property, check if it is supported

For further information, refer this:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding `position: fixed;` to your text. It will fix the position of your text even on scroll. You just have to change some styling to adjust the display.

This is the running snippet for it.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 40px;">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 80px; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Raleway'; position: fixed;width: 50%;" id="lookAtThesePhotos">Look at these photos</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%;">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/hackers.jpg">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
            <img style="float: right;" src="https://mv-hacks.com/images/event/mrnguyen.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```